# how to override magento 1.9 newsletter model subscriber.php

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, magento-1.9

I'm trying to add first name and last name on my newsletter subscription. I would like to override the newsletter core functions the controller and the subscriber model.
Here are my code:
config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<config> 
<modules> 
    <My_Newsletter> 
        <version>0.1.0</version> 
    </My_Newsletter> 
</modules> 
<global>
    <models>
        <newsletter>
            <rewrite>
                <subscriber>My_Newsletter_Model_Newsletter_Subscriber</subscriber>
            </rewrite>
        </newsletter>
    </models>
</global>
<frontend> 
    <routers> 
        <newsletter> 
            <args> 
                <modules> 
                    <My_Newsletter before="Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController">My_Newsletter</My_Newsletter> 
                </modules> 
            </args> 
        </newsletter> 
    </routers> 
</frontend> 
</config>
```

Controller.php

```
<?php
include_once("Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php");
class My_Newsletter_SubscriberController extends Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController {
public function newAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
        $session            = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        $customerSession    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $email              = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
        $firtname = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('firstname');
        $lastname = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('lastname');

        try {
            if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('Please enter a valid email address.'));
            }

            if (Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::XML_PATH_ALLOW_GUEST_SUBSCRIBE_FLAG) != 1 && 
                !$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('Sorry, but administrator denied subscription for guests. Please <a href="%s">register</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getRegisterUrl()));
            }

            $ownerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                    ->loadByEmail($email)
                    ->getId();
            if ($ownerId !== null && $ownerId != $customerSession->getId()) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('This email address is already assigned to another user.'));
            }

            $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email,$firtname,$lastname);
            if ($status == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                $session->addSuccess($this->__('Confirmation request has been sent.'));
            }
            else {
                $session->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
            }
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription: %s', $e->getMessage()));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription.'));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirectReferer();
}
}
```

subscriber.php

```
<?php
include_once("Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php");
class My_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
const STATUS_SUBSCRIBED     = 1;
const STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE     = 2;
const STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED   = 3;
const STATUS_UNCONFIRMED    = 4;

const XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE       = 'newsletter/subscription/confirm_email_template';
const XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_IDENTITY       = 'newsletter/subscription/confirm_email_identity';
const XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE       = 'newsletter/subscription/success_email_template';
const XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY       = 'newsletter/subscription/success_email_identity';
const XML_PATH_UNSUBSCRIBE_EMAIL_TEMPLATE   = 'newsletter/subscription/un_email_template';
const XML_PATH_UNSUBSCRIBE_EMAIL_IDENTITY   = 'newsletter/subscription/un_email_identity';
const XML_PATH_CONFIRMATION_FLAG            = 'newsletter/subscription/confirm';
const XML_PATH_ALLOW_GUEST_SUBSCRIBE_FLAG   = 'newsletter/subscription/allow_guest_subscribe';

/**
 * @deprecated since 1.4.0.1
 */
const XML_PATH_SENDING_SET_RETURN_PATH      = Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::XML_PATH_SENDING_SET_RETURN_PATH;

/**
 * Prefix of model events names
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_eventPrefix = 'newsletter_subscriber';

/**
 * Parameter name in event
 *
 * In observe method you can use $observer->getEvent()->getObject() in this case
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_eventObject = 'subscriber';

/**
 * True if data changed
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_isStatusChanged = false;

/**
 * Initialize resource model
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('newsletter/subscriber');
}

/**
 * Alias for getSubscriberId()
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->getSubscriberId();
}

/**
 * Alias for setSubscriberId()
 *
 * @param int $value
 */
public function setId($value)
{
    return $this->setSubscriberId($value);
}

/**
 * Alias for getSubscriberConfirmCode()
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCode()
{
    return $this->getSubscriberConfirmCode();
}

/**
 * Return link for confirmation of subscription
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getConfirmationLink() {
    return Mage::helper('newsletter')->getConfirmationUrl($this);
}

/**
 * Returns Insubscribe url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUnsubscriptionLink() {
    return Mage::helper('newsletter')->getUnsubscribeUrl($this);
}

/**
 * Alias for setSubscriberConfirmCode()
 *
 * @param string $value
 */
public function setCode($value)
{
    return $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($value);
}

/**
 * Alias for getSubscriberStatus()
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->getSubscriberStatus();
}

/**
 * Alias for setSubscriberStatus()
 *
 * @param int
 */
public function setStatus($value)
{
    return $this->setSubscriberStatus($value);
}

/**
 * Set the error messages scope for subscription
 *
 * @param boolean $scope
 * @return Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
 */

public function setMessagesScope($scope)
{
    $this->getResource()->setMessagesScope($scope);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Alias for getSubscriberEmail()
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->getSubscriberEmail();
}

/**
 * Alias for setSubscriberEmail()
 *
 * @param string $value
 */
public function setEmail($value)
{
    return $this->setSubscriberEmail($value);
}

/**
 * Set for status change flag
 *
 * @param boolean $value
 */
public function setIsStatusChanged($value)
{
    $this->_isStatusChanged = (boolean) $value;
       return $this;
}

/**
 * Return status change flag value
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getIsStatusChanged()
{
    return $this->_isStatusChanged;
}

/**
 * Return customer subscription status
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isSubscribed()
{
    if($this->getId() && $this->getStatus()==self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


 /**
 * Load subscriber data from resource model by email
 *
 * @param int $subscriberId
 */
public function loadByEmail($subscriberEmail)
{
    $this->addData($this->getResource()->loadByEmail($subscriberEmail));
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Load subscriber info by customer
 *
 * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer
 * @return Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
 */
public function loadByCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
{
    $data = $this->getResource()->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $this->addData($data);
    if (!empty($data) && $customer->getId() && !$this->getCustomerId()) {
        $this->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
        $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($this->randomSequence());
        if ($this->getStatus()==self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
            $this->setStatus($customer->getIsSubscribed() ? self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED : self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED);
        }
        $this->save();
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Returns sting of random chars
 *
 * @param int $length
 * @return string
 */
public function randomSequence($length=32)
{
    $id = '';
    $par = array();
    $char = array_merge(range('a','z'),range(0,9));
    $charLen = count($char)-1;
    for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
        $disc = mt_rand(0, $charLen);
        $par[$i] = $char[$disc];
        $id = $id.$char[$disc];
    }
    return $id;
}

/**
 * Subscribes by email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @throws Exception
 * @return int
 */
public function subscribe($email,$firstname,$lastname)
{
    $this->loadByEmail($email);
    $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

    if(!$this->getId()) {
        $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($this->randomSequence());
    }

    $isConfirmNeed   = (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMATION_FLAG) == 1) ? true : false;
    $isOwnSubscribes = false;
    $ownerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
        ->loadByEmail($email)
        ->getId();
    $isSubscribeOwnEmail = $customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $ownerId == $customerSession->getId();

    if (!$this->getId() || $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED
        || $this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE
    ) {
        if ($isConfirmNeed === true) {
            // if user subscribes own login email - confirmation is not needed
            $isOwnSubscribes = $isSubscribeOwnEmail;
            if ($isOwnSubscribes == true){
                $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
            } else {
                $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE);
            }
        } else {
            $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED);
        }
        $this->setSubscriberEmail($email);
        $this->setSubscriberFirstname($firstname);
        $this->setSubscriberLastname($lastname);
    }

    if ($isSubscribeOwnEmail) {
        $this->setStoreId($customerSession->getCustomer()->getStoreId());
        $this->setCustomerId($customerSession->getCustomerId());
    } else {
        $this->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $this->setCustomerId(0);
    }

    $this->setIsStatusChanged(true);

    try {
        $this->save();
        if ($isConfirmNeed === true
            && $isOwnSubscribes === false
        ) {
            $this->sendConfirmationRequestEmail();
        } else {
            $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
        }

        return $this->getStatus();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Unsubscribes loaded subscription
 *
 */
public function unsubscribe()
{
    if ($this->hasCheckCode() && $this->getCode() != $this->getCheckCode()) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Invalid subscription confirmation code.'));
    }

    $this->setSubscriberStatus(self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED)
        ->save();
    $this->sendUnsubscriptionEmail();
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Saving customer subscription status
 *
 * @param   Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer
 * @return  Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
 */
public function subscribeCustomer($customer)
{
    $this->loadByCustomer($customer);

    if ($customer->getImportMode()) {
        $this->setImportMode(true);
    }

    if (!$customer->getIsSubscribed() && !$this->getId()) {
        // If subscription flag not set or customer is not a subscriber
        // and no subscribe below
        return $this;
    }

    if(!$this->getId()) {
        $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($this->randomSequence());
    }

   /*
    * Logical mismatch between customer registration confirmation code and customer password confirmation
    */
   $confirmation = null;
   if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired() && ($customer->getConfirmation() != $customer->getPassword())) {
       $confirmation = $customer->getConfirmation();
   }

    $sendInformationEmail = false;
    if ($customer->hasIsSubscribed()) {
        $status = $customer->getIsSubscribed()
            ? (!is_null($confirmation) ? self::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED : self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
            : self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED;
        /**
         * If subscription status has been changed then send email to the customer
         */
        if ($status != self::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED && $status != $this->getStatus()) {
            $sendInformationEmail = true;
        }
    } elseif (($this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_UNCONFIRMED) && (is_null($confirmation))) {
        $status = self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED;
        $sendInformationEmail = true;
    } else {
        $status = ($this->getStatus() == self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE ? self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED : $this->getStatus());
    }

    if($status != $this->getStatus()) {
        $this->setIsStatusChanged(true);
    }

    $this->setStatus($status);

    if(!$this->getId()) {
        $storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
        if ($customer->getStoreId() == 0) {
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getWebsite($customer->getWebsiteId())->getDefaultStore()->getId();
        }
        $this->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setEmail($customer->getEmail());
    } else {
        $this->setStoreId($customer->getStoreId())
            ->setEmail($customer->getEmail());
    }

    $this->save();
    $sendSubscription = $customer->getData('sendSubscription') || $sendInformationEmail;
    if (is_null($sendSubscription) xor $sendSubscription) {
        if ($this->getIsStatusChanged() && $status == self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED) {
            $this->sendUnsubscriptionEmail();
        } elseif ($this->getIsStatusChanged() && $status == self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED) {
            $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Confirms subscriber newsletter
 *
 * @param string $code
 * @return boolean
 */
public function confirm($code)
{
    if($this->getCode()==$code) {
        $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
            ->setIsStatusChanged(true)
            ->save();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Mark receiving subscriber of queue newsletter
 *
 * @param  Mage_Newsletter_Model_Queue $queue
 * @return boolean
 */
public function received(Mage_Newsletter_Model_ $queue)
{
    $this->getResource()->received($this,$queue);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Sends out confirmation email
 *
 * @return Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
 */
public function sendConfirmationRequestEmail()
{
    if ($this->getImportMode()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if(!Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE)
       || !Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_IDENTITY)
    )  {
        return $this;
    }

    $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
    $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

    $email = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

    // $email->sendTransactional(
    //     Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    //     Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    //     $this->getEmail(),
    //     $this->getName(),
    //     array('subscriber'=>$this)
    // );

    $email->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
        $this->getEmail(),
        $this->getName(),
        array('subscriber'=>$this, 'unsubscribe' =>$this->getUnsubscriptionLink())
    );

    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Sends out confirmation success email
 *
 * @return Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
 */
public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
{
    if ($this->getImportMode()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if(!Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE)
       || !Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY)
    ) {
        return $this;
    }

    $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
    $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

    $email = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

    $email->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
        $this->getEmail(),
        $this->getName(),
        array('subscriber'=>$this)
    );

    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Sends out unsubsciption email
 *
 * @return Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
 */
public function sendUnsubscriptionEmail()
{
    if ($this->getImportMode()) {
        return $this;
    }
    if(!Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_UNSUBSCRIBE_EMAIL_TEMPLATE)
       || !Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_UNSUBSCRIBE_EMAIL_IDENTITY)
    ) {
        return $this;
    }

    $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
    $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

    $email = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

    $email->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_UNSUBSCRIBE_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_UNSUBSCRIBE_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
        $this->getEmail(),
        $this->getName(),
        array('subscriber'=>$this)
    );

    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrieve Subscribers Full Name if it was set
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getSubscriberFullName()
{
    $name = null;
    if ($this->hasCustomerFirstname() || $this->hasCustomerLastname()) {
        $name = Mage::helper('customer')->getFullCustomerName($this);
    }
    return $name;
}
/**
* Alias for getSubscriberFirstname()
*
* @return string
*/
public function getFirstname()
{
    return $this->getSubscriberFirstname();
}

/**
* Alias for setSubscriberFirstName()
*
* @param string $value
*/
public function setFirstname($value)
{
    return $this->setSubscriberFirstname($value);
}

/**
* Alias for getSubscriberLastname()
*
* @return string
*/
public function getLastname()
{
    return $this->getSubscriberLastname();
}

/**
* Alias for setSubscriberLastname()
*
* @param string $value
*/
public function setLastname($value)
{
    return $this->setSubscriberLastname($value);
}
}
```

I add a getter and setter on the subscriber model add $firstname,$lastname on the subscribe function
the problem is, when sending, the page doesn't load anymore and the admin list is not showing.

I suspect that I have  a problem on the config.xml on overriding the subscriber.php model

Answer (score 0):

There are no such columns `subscriber_firstname` and `subscriber_lastname`already exist in `newsletter_subscriber` table. By default magento display first name and last name for only those subscribers who was registered as customer through their customer_ids `newsletter_subscriber`.`customer_id`. In order to save additional information in subscriber table you have to create new columns first.